# target number input change

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, live-update

I have a number input field and I want to show live updates of my price when either the number is incremented or decremented using the up/down button or a user types in the price. Here is what I have so far. How can it target the do this? 
HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>  
    <td>QUANTITY: <input type="number" style="width: 50px "ng-model="quant" ng-init="quant = 1"/></td>
    <td>TOTAL:{{total}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="goPrice(quant)">PRICE</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.goPrice = function(quant){
    $scope.total= quant * 9.99
    console.log($scope.total)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```
<input
  ng-model="string"
  [name="string"]
  [required="string"]
  [ng-required="boolean"]
  [ng-minlength="number"]
  [ng-maxlength="number"]
  [ng-pattern="string"]
  [ng-change="expression"]
  [ng-trim="boolean"]>
...
</input>
```

Specifically this

```
[ng-change="expression"]
ng-change="change()"
```